# How can i remove / open up this Broan bathroom vent fan / heater?

Tags: vent, exhaust-fan

Does anyone have tips on how I can get this Broan vent fan down from where it's mounted on my bathroom ceiling?  I am really struggling and dont want to break it.  Tried pulling, twisting, and also attempted removing the lens from the middle section.  Also tried looking up user manual but wasn't very helpful.  I could get my camera lens up to see the inside a little better but still am not able to figure it out.

(The motor is very loud and I'm hoping to get in there and see if there's anything i can do)

Thanks!

[image]
[image]

Comment: That photo is hard to see but makes me think that the translucent light cover is squeezed from the sides to come free and underneath there is a screw in the middle holding the cover to the fan box.

Comment: Usually there are spring-loaded arms gripping the drywall.  They can be fussy, and there's no way to guess which way the need to be pushed or pulled to help free them.  If you put a light up inside the ceiling there, start your  phone video recording, hold it up there and move it around slowly, you might see what you need to do.  Now this might be completely wrong but I think maybe I see a spring clip in your second photo [here](https://imgur.com/a/Uevz1xq)

Comment: I'd usually agree with @jay613, but I suspect that this one has a nut behind the light lens. Get that off (putty knife at the edge, maybe) and see.

Comment: thanks @jay613 and @aloysiusdefenestrate! both your answers helped me figure it out - getting a vid helped me realize i needed to pop off the cover with a knife

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Et voilà!

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lAu0upTMfXc

Summary, in case the video disappears:

- Remove the light cover by popping it off with a screwdriver on the side
- Remove the center bolt to release the light/fan cover
- Unplug the light and set the light/fan cover aside
- Heat fan and exhaust fan can then be removed/replaced or everything taken out.
- The video does not show this, but once you remove the heat fan and exhaust fan it should be clear what screws need to be removed to take out the entire unit for replacement, if needed.

Comment: Of course you can also just get replacement fan units, since they simply bolt/plug in. Did that when mine failed; upgraded the airflow rating while I was at it.

Comment: thank you!  not sure why i wasn't able to discover that in my googling but that's it!

Answer (score 4):

Combo vent/light units with a replaceable light bulb (not integrated LEDs) usually have a fastener holding the metal light assembly to the plastic part of the cover. Check for a single screw or nut, which may be located behind the bulb.

Edit: Yes, there is a special place in...

Comment: thanks !  this one ended up being one where i had to pup off the lens over the light

Comment: The first one for me was behind the light bulb. Took me three days to figure out!